# Is It possible to build asp.net core project using MSBuild from code?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, asp.net-core

I want to build asp.net core project using another C# project. Here is the sample code. ( I am using Visual Studio 2015)

```
var projectCollection = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection(Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetDefinitionLocations.Registry);
projectCollection.DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0";
projectCollection.RegisterLogger(new Microsoft.Build.Logging.ConsoleLogger(Microsoft.Build.Framework.LoggerVerbosity.Detailed));
var project = projectCollection.LoadProject(@"H:\Development\WebApplication22\src\WebApplication22\WebApplication22.xproj");
bool b = project.Build();
```

It gives me many errors. Following is one of them.

> The "GetTransitiveNonDotNetProjectDependencies" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks.dll.
>   Method 'get_BuildEngine' in type 'Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks.KProcess'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an
>   implementation. Confirm that the  declaration is correct,
>   that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the
>   task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. Done building target
>   "_GetDependencyFragmentFiles" in project "WebApplication22. xproj" --
>   FAILED.

Note : If I am using Visual Studio Command Prompt and use MSbuild then it works fine.

Comment: May be this link useful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild

Comment: I made a test with your code, it reproduce same error. I suggest that you could call MSBuild command programmatically to build project. On the other hand, you may refer to this tool code: https://github.com/dotnet/buildtools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No for now. When you run msbuild from Visual Studio Command Prompt to build a asp.net core project, it will call dotnet.exe to build.

MS is working on moving from .xproj/project.json to .csproj/MSBuild currently and most possible to be available in Visual Studio 15 RTM. You can refer to this link for more information: [Changes to Project.json](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/).

> The first wave of this change will happen in the Visual Studio “15”
>   RTM: when opening any .NET Core project in Visual Studio, it will
>   automatically convert from .xproj to .csproj, moving the assets from
>   the project.json file into configuration files and the .csproj file.
>   We will also provide a tool for converting applications using the .NET
>   command line tools as well.