# How to build DotNet Core project using MSBuild programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, msbuild

I want to build .Net Core 3.1 solution which has API Project with Businesslayer and 2 more layers from C# code. I am using BuildManager to build solution.

```
        string projectFileName = @"D:\SampleUserApplication\SampleUserApplication.sln";
        ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
        Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
        GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
        GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", solution_name);
        //GlobalProperty.Add("MSBuildExtensionsPath", msbuildRoot);

        BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
        bp.Loggers = new[] {
        new FileLogger
        {
           Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed,
           ShowSummary = true,
           SkipProjectStartedText = true
        }
        };

        BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BeginBuild(bp);

        BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

        BuildSubmission BuildSubmission = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.PendBuildRequest(BuildRequest);
        BuildSubmission.Execute();
        BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.EndBuild();
        if (BuildSubmission.BuildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure)
        {
            //throw new Exception();
        }
```

But the build fails with following errors:

> MSBUILD : warning MSB4196: The "*.overridetasks" files could not be successfully loaded from their expected location "D:\NOCodeRespository\NoCode\NoCode\NoCodeAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1". Default tasks will not be overridden. 
>
> MSBUILD : warning MSB4010: The "*.tasks" files could not be successfully loaded from their expected location "D:\NOCodeRespository\NoCode\NoCode\NoCodeAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1". Default tasks will not be available.
> D:\SampleUserApplication\SampleUserApplication.sln.metaproj : 
> error MSB4036: The "Message" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "D:\NOCodeRespository\NoCode\NoCode\NoCodeAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1" directory.
> Done building target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in project "SampleUserApplication.sln" -- FAILED.
> Done building project "SampleUserApplication.sln" -- FAILED.
> Build FAILED.

I tried adding environment variables like:

```
        var msbuildRoot = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild";
        // var msbuildExe = Path.Combine(msbuildRoot, @"19.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe");
        var sdkPath = Path.Combine(msbuildRoot, "Sdks");
        //Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBUILD_EXE_PATH", msbuildExe);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBUILDSDKSPATH", sdkPath);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildExtensionsPath", msbuildRoot);
```

and  finally

```
        GlobalProperty.Add("MSBuildExtensionsPath", msbuildRoot);
```

but nothing worked out. I didnt find any solution after long googling also. I hope some one has solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934699/is-it-possible-to-build-asp-net-core-project-using-msbuild-from-code

Comment: Why exactly isn’t the dotnet core cli sufficient?